# pd.read_csv gives entire data in object dtype. How do I convert to int type?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, object, integer

I am trying to read the a particular csv (plane-data.csv) but the entire df is in object type. I require 'year' to be in integer type so that I can perform calculations.

Please take look at my [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onDYM.png)

My dataset is from [plane-data.csv link](https://dataverse.harvard.edu/file.xhtml?persistentId=doi:10.7910/DVN/HG7NV7/XXSL8A&version=1.0)

Would really love to have some help, I have been searching the entire internet for 6 hours with no progress. Thank you !

Initially, I tried

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('plane-data.csv')
columns =  ['type', 'manufacturer', 'issue_date', 'model', 'status', 'aircraft_type', 'engine_type']
df.drop(columns, axis=1, inplace=True)
df.dropna(inplace=True)

df['year'] = df['year'].astype(int)
```

and got

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'None'
```

Which I have found to be the result of NaN values.

I have cleared all nullvalues and tried using

```
df['year'] = df['year'].astype(str).astype('Int64')
```

from other SO posts that seems to work for them  not for me. I got

```
TypeError: object cannot be converted to an IntegerDtype
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable
```

because you used [] instead of () in `df['year'] = df['year'].astype[int]`. You should use `df['year'] = df['year'].astype(int)`

Comment: oh yes my bad, typo! Thanks for pointing it out! But I still get errors even with the correct syntax :(

Answer (score 0):

Since the column `year` contains a string value (literally `None`), pandas is consedering the whole column as `object`. You can handle that by simply setting `na_values=['None']` as an argument of [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) :

```
df = pd.read_csv('plane-data.csv', na_values=['None'])
```

Or, you can use [`pandas.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) :

```
df = pd.read_csv('plane-data.csv')

df['year']= pd.to_numeric(df['year'], errors='coerce') # invalid parsing will be set as NaN
```

##### # Output :

```
print(df.dtypes)

tailnum           object
type              object
manufacturer      object
issue_date        object
model             object
status            object
aircraft_type     object
engine_type       object
year             float64
dtype: object
```